# XAMPP installer has black background and no text

Tags: linux, background, xampp, installation

On my laptop which runs Arch Linux (with xfce4 as the window manager), every time I try to install anything for XAMPP (like installing XAMPP itself or things like WordPress) I download the installer, I do `chmod a+x` on the file to allow me to run it, and then I do ./whatever.the.name.of.the.installer.is and the installer runs. The problem is that it has a black background with either black text or no text so I can't see it. Like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr6cZ.png).

Can someone explain how to fix this, or at least why it is happening? So far I have had to get by doing a google image search of the title of each panel to see what the panel is supposed to look like and then clicking where the button should be, but that's been frustrating and it's just a shot in the dark (literally).

Answer (score 0):

Start the installer with the `--mode gtk` flag.